# What data type or structure to use to store a monetary value and a currency in R?

Tags: r, currency

I have to do some calculations in R with monetary values in different currencies (e.g. 10.02 DOL, 00.12 CAD, 123.32 EUR, ...). What yould be the best way to store a value and the corresponing currency in R?

At the moment I have a dataframe with the two columns "Value" and "ReferenceCurrency" amongst others. Is there a sensible way to store the two columns in one?

I am not asking for a way to format this as an output, but to store it in a way that I can do currency conversion and other operations with the value depending on the currency it is in.

Comment: If your goal is to do currency conversion and this type of operation a dataframe with two column: one numeric for value, and the other character (or factor) for currency seems good enough

Comment: You could create a look-up table with conversion factors (or get one from some web API). Then it would be easy to do the conversions. Of course, you could create a `currency` object and write a conversion function for it. Soemone might already have done that and provide a package, but I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `match`-function delivers a numeric index that can be used to pull a value from a vector:

```
> convert <- data.frame( country = c("USD", "euro", "HKD"), fact= c( 1.4, 1, 8)  )
> convert
  country fact
1     USD  1.4
2    euro  1.0
3     HKD  8.0
> dat <- data.frame( transact = LETTERS[1:10], curr = sample(1:10, 10) , country=sample( c("USD", "euro", "HKD"), 10 , rep=TRUE) )
> dat
   transact curr country
1         A    4     USD
2         B    1    euro
3         C    3     USD
4         D    6    euro
5         E    2     USD
6         F    9    euro
7         G    5     USD
8         H    8    euro
9         I   10     USD
10        J    7     HKD
> dat$EUequiv <- dat$curr/convert$fact[ match(dat$country, convert$country)]
> dat
   transact curr country  EUequiv
1         A    4     USD 2.857143
2         B    1    euro 1.000000
3         C    3     USD 2.142857
4         D    6    euro 6.000000
5         E    2     USD 1.428571
6         F    9    euro 9.000000
7         G    5     USD 3.571429
8         H    8    euro 8.000000
9         I   10     USD 7.142857
10        J    7     HKD 0.875000
```